# django register user as superuser

Tags: django, user-permissions

I am using a OneToOne relationship to create a custom user like this:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(Django_User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)
    birthday=models.DateField(auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD='username'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Patient, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def set_birthday(self, birthday):
        birthday = self.birthday
```

Now there have been some additions to my task and i need to give every user is_staff or is_superuser permissions.
I created a form:

```
class UserPermissionForm(forms.Form):
permission = [(1, 'Patient'),
(2, 'Lieferant'),
(3, 'Andere'),
(4, 'Mitarbeiter'),
(5, 'Admin')]
Zugriffsrechte = forms.ChoiceField(choices= permission, widget=forms.Select())
```

And tried setting the permissions in my view - genericform is just the usual django user creation form, form is the form where the birthday is set and permission is the form seen above:

```
def register_user_view(request):
    title="Register User"
    genericform = GenericCreationForm(request.POST or None)
    form=UserRegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    permission = UserPermissionForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid() * genericform.is_valid() * permission.is_valid():
        genericform.save()
        username = genericform.cleaned_data.get('username')
        raw_password = genericform.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        user_type = int(request.POST.get('Zugriffsrechte'))
        new_user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
        profile = form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = new_user
        profile.save()
        is_superuser = False
        is_staff = False
        if user_type > 3:
            is_staff = True
            print('YOU SHALL BE STAFF')
        if user_type > 4:
            is_superuser = True
            print('YOU SHALL BE ADMIN')
        profile.user.is_staff = is_staff
        profile.user.is_superuser = is_superuser
        login(request,profile.user)
        return redirect("/register/done")
    context={
        "form":form,
        "genericform":genericform,
        "permissionform": permission,
        "title":title,
    }
    return render(request,"profile_form.html",context)
```

My first question is if and how i could set is_staff or is_superuser. The code above causes no errors but the created user is still just a regular user.
Also i know this can be simplyfied (i am working with other people so at some point everything got a bit unstructured) so question 2 is: what is the best approach to make this code better? A custom user with a custom user manager? Or is the OneToOne Field still a good option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are missing on the saving part. Add `profile.save()` after you are changing it. Something like this.

```
profile.user.is_staff = is_staff
profile.user.is_superuser = is_superuser
profile.save()
```

Comment: profile.user.save() worked!
THANK YOU! Such a dumb mistake =D

Comment: Glad I could help. :)